# Cid of model change when remove model in collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have 1 problem very stupid with cid of models.
When i add some model into collection then i remove 1 of them, but cid of other models are changed. I don't understand the problem happen with my code
Add model to collection:

```html
addSchedule: function () {
        var schedule = this.model.schedules.push({touch_plan_id: this.model.get('id')});
        this.selective = 'sch_' + this.model.schedules.last().cid;
        console.log(this.model.schedules);
    },
```

remove models from collection :

```html
removeSchedule: function () {;
        var activeDOM = $('.active');
        var cid = activeDOM.attr('id');
        if (cid) {
            var schedule = this.model.schedules.get(cid);
            if (schedule.get('id')) {
                schedule.destroy({wait: true});
            } else {
                this.model.schedules.remove(schedule);
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: What is `schedules`..? Why are you reading stuff from DOM..? Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: schedeules is 1 models collection , i get cid from DOM

Comment: So, with this code, why do you think cid of other models changed..? What is not working? Nothing is clear from your question

Comment: i add 4 models into schedule collection as https://gyazo.com/81409a405bf06be1f6af9d4c947765e2 then i remove models has  cid = c13 but in schedule collection has cid of model = c13 again as https://gyazo.com/c905fe3a1f6bcf4f4418c1e9305043b8

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you are in a hurry to get the right answer so you can move along, but there is something you are missing that is more important. If you don't understand this, you might as well use jQuery because you are not using Backbone as intended.

If you insist on doing this very wrong, very bad, very inefficient, very unprofessional thing you are trying to do, here is my take - the rule of the `cid` is that it is created at the time of model creation by `Backbone` using the `underscorejs` `uniqueId` function. You are somehow trying to associate the `DOM` `id` with the `cid` of a **MODEL**, which makes zero sense. You are confused and unless you post your code, instead of videos of yourself debugging, nobody will be able to help!

One big point of Backbone is to **deal with logical objects and not the DOM**. It looks like you are trying to remove a `Schedule` based on whether the class `active` is applied to something.

Your logic looks something like this to me:

1. Look for `$('.active')` (by the way this could be more than one thing, don't you think that's a problem?)
2. See if it has an `id` attribute defined on it, ie, it has an element ID
3. If it does, find the `Schedule` from `this.model.schedules` by using `get` and the `cid` (Can you do that? How do you know you won't get a null pointer exception by the way???)
4. If the `schedule`'s **BACKBONE** `id` attribute exists, destroy the schedule. If not, remove the schedule from the collection. In case you do not know, the Backbone ID has **NOTHING** to do with the DOM ID.

Does this make sense to you? Come on, I know you cannot be satisfied with this.

Before you go further down this road to nowhere, stop a moment and think what you want to do.

I'm going to assume you want to remove any `Schedule` marked `active`.

Here's what I propose, and I'm sure what you know to be the reasonable approach:

1. Set an attribute on the `Schedule` model called `active`
2. Handle changes to `active` using Backbone Events, for instance, by updating a `DOM` element on change of `active`.
3. Handle removal without looking at the DOM:

`schedules.remove(schedules.where({active: true}));`

Now on the point 2, the event, it is really easy and pleasant to use.

```
...
var ScheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() { 
        ...
        this.$el.html(blah);
        var _this = this;
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:active', function(schedule, activeOrNot) {
             if (activeOrNot === true) { _this.$el.addClass('active'); }
             else { _this.$el.removeClass('active'); }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: *"unless you post your code, instead of videos of yourself debugging, nobody will be able to help!"* - You said it yourself. You seem to have enough rep to close vote... Please use comments to ask for more info, or close the question. If the OP makes an effort and improves the question, then re-open and answer it. I'm wondering who upvoted this question.. well... Please don't encourage questions like this... If you encourage crap you'll be bombarded with crap -_-